# Conditional variant type depending on class template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a class template and essentially want to create a template alias for a variant type that will be exposed to API users:

```
template <bool InsertsAllowed, DeletesAllowed>
class Executor {
   ...

 public:
   // Ideally, would be
   // std::variant<ReadRequest, {InsertRequest only if InsertsAllowed}, {DeleteRequest only if DeletesAllowed}>
   // e.g. InsertsAllowed = true, DeletesAllowed = False ==> std::variant<ReadRequest, InsertRequest>
   // InsertsAllowed = true, DeletesAllowed = True ==> std::variant<ReadRequest, InsertRequest, DeleteRequest>
   using RequestType = ...

   makeRequest(const RequestType &r);

   ...
}
```

So far, the best solution I could come up with is

```
template <bool InsertsAllowed, DeletesAllowed>
class Executor {
   ...

 public:
   struct BAD_TYPE = {};
   using RequestType = std::variant<
      ReadRequest,
      std::conditional<InsertsAllowed, InsertRequest, BAD_TYPE>,
      std::conditional<DeleletesAllowed, DeleteRequest, BAD_TYPE>>;

   makeRequest(const RequestType &r);

   ...
}
```

but this doesn't exactly do what I set out to achieve and isn't the cleanest solution anyway.

I need to be able to make a reference to `RequestType`, so unfortunately I can't replace `BAD_TYPE` with `void`. Also, I'd like to avoid stacking a bunch of conditionals to achieve my goal, in the case that I will need to add more template arguments to similar effect.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hm not quite sure what you're getting at, but I did update the post with the more correct terminology

Comment: Much better. It helps when people know what others are asking about.

Comment: What you need is a typelist (that's the way it is called). Read this : https://www.codingwiththomas.com/blog/getting-started-with-typelists.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a meta-function to conditionally append another type to the template argument list of `std::variant`. Let's name it `condit_append`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

template<bool cond, typename A, typename B>
struct condit_append;

template<bool cond, typename U, typename ...T>
struct condit_append<cond, std::variant<T...>, U>
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<cond,
        std::variant<T..., U>,
        std::variant<T...>
        >;
};
```

Next, let's create a convenience alias to it similar to how it is done for standard traits:

```
template<bool cond, typename ...T>
using condit_append_t = typename condit_append<cond, T...>::type;
```

Finally, use it for your class:

```
    class ReadRequest;
    class InsertRequest;
    class DeleteRequest;
    template <bool InsertsAllowed, bool DeletesAllowed>
    class Executor {
        using Type1 = std::variant<ReadRequest>;
        using Type2 = condit_append_t<InsertsAllowed,Type1, InsertRequest>;
    public:
        using RequestType = condit_append_t<DeletesAllowed,Type2, DeleteRequest>;
         //...
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::tuple` already has function [`std::tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat).

So you might have:

```
using RequestTypeTuple = decltype(std::tuple_cat(
     std::declval<std::tuple<ReadRequest>>(),
     std::declval<std::conditional_t<InsertsAllowed,
                                     std::tuple<InsertRequest>, std::tuple<>>>(),
     std::declval<std::conditional_t<DeleletesAllowed,
                                     std::tuple<DeleteRequest>, std::tuple<>>>()
     ));
```

Then a simple "mapping" traits to transform tuple as variant:

```
template <typename> struct to_variant_impl;

template <typename... Ts> struct to_variant_impl<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::variant<Ts...>;
};
template <typename T>
using to_variant_t = typename to_variant_impl<T>::type;
```

So your class would be:

```
template <bool InsertsAllowed, DeletesAllowed>
class Executor {
    using RequestTypeTuple = decltype(std::tuple_cat(
        std::declval<std::tuple<ReadRequest>>(),
        std::declval<std::conditional_t<InsertsAllowed,
                                       std::tuple<InsertRequest>, std::tuple<>>>(),
        std::declval<std::conditional_t<DeleletesAllowed,
                                        std::tuple<DeleteRequest>, std::tuple<>>>()
     ));
public:
   using RequestType = to_variant_t<RequestTypeTuple>;

// ...
};
```